# How could a page be cached and expire upon folder change?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a page that is to be cached, currently I use:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

I understand that for OutputCahe, the content can be cached based on a expiry time OR a file change. However, I want the cached page to never expire unless the number of files contained in a folder changed. Is that possible?

Because the cached page is a folder tree, I do not want it to load everytime as it takes a long time to load (due to its recursive indexing). However I do want it to reload if the folder tree changed its structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add cache dependence to your response, somewhere in your backcode. also increase your duration from 60 to maximum possibly max value of int64.

```
     Response.AddFileDependency("Your folder path");
```